# Close all Safari tabs/windows that do not match a set of names

Tags: applescript

I am VERY new to AppleScript and usually end up copying scripts I find on the Internet and tailoring them to my needs.

What I am attempting to do now is create a script that closes any and all Safari tabs that do not match three specific names (my work windows that I must leave open).

I found a very simple code that ALMOST accomplishes what I want...but with only window name, not three.

```
tell application "Safari" to close (every window whose name does not contain "Voice Portal")
```

Ideally, it would close everything that did not contain "Voice Portal", "Google Hangouts", and "Resources".

Can anybody steer me in the right direction as to how I can accomplish this? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will achieve what you were looking for.

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell its windows
        close (its tabs whose name does not contain "Voice Portal" and ¬
            name does not contain "Google Hangouts" and ¬
            name does not contain "Resources")
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: That one doesn't close any windows for me. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯